# Rule "Restart computer" failed when installing SQL Server 2008

Tags: windows-7, installation, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When trying to install SQL Server 2008 Developer and Enterprise editions on a Windows 7 box I've got this message:

> Rule "Restart computer" failed.
>   A computer restart is required. You must restart this computer before installing SQL Server.

Of course I already restarted 10 times.

I've found [a post in a forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/ca182f5d-114a-4516-99d4-0854ad176fbf) saying that I should clear

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations
```

but I don't have such a key.

Comment: Are you running any other versions or instances of sql server or any other servers for that matter?

Comment: I had sql server 2005 express installed with visual studio 2008.

Comment: Clearing that Reg Key worked for me

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176857/installation-problem-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's a better solution, but the only one I could find was re-installing. Mental note: always install SQL Server first.

Answer (score 14):

**.... after installing SQL Server 2008 Express, put the value (might be multiple lines) back into this setting.  So copy them somewhere!**

**Fix:**

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager` is the path.  `Session Manager` is the folder.  `PendingFileRenameOperations` is the setting.  Clear the value in that setting.

**Common mistake:**

You'll notice that there are more folders under the `Session Manager` folder.  Don't look there.  Those are sub-folders.  Once you've clicked on the `Session Manager` folder, find the setting on the right.

Answer (score 7):

I've tried SkipRules option from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/184386/603516) with SQL Server Express 2014:

- run `SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe` just to extract files then close it
- `cd SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU`
- `setup.exe /ACTION=INSTALL /X86 /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck`

Then the setup process didn't complain on "Reboot required" rule but still failed at the end with the following messages:

> A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes
>   to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer and then run Setup
>   again.
>
> One or more affected files have operations pending. You must restart
>   your computer after the setup process is completed.

Then I tried to temporarily delete both registry keys `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired` mentioned in other answers here.
After that setup run smoothly and everything worked without reboot.

Comment: My SQL Server wouldn't start and required a reinstall, this was the only way to get rid of it.

Answer (score 6):

like stated in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hansr/archive/2006/02/17/patchreboot.aspx
there is also an important key from windowsupdate

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired
```

this must also be 0 or not present.

Answer (score 2):

When the tricks with clearing the registry keys don't work:
- HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired

You might try a reboot from the command line.
Press Windows+R for the "Run" dialog box and type cmd and press enter to start the command line.

The command for a forced reboot with zero seconds delay is "**shutdown -r -f -t 0**".

This might be handy when you use a Windows 8 computer or a Win8.1 because a shutdown is sometimes not a real shutdown but a "hybrid shutdown" which is in fact a hibernate state to enable "Fast Boot".

Comment: +1 this was the only thing that worked out of the suggestions in this thread and the MSDN threads.

Answer (score 1):

Go into `Windows -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services` and stop all of the `SQL Server Services`.  Then just hit `Re-run`.

Comment: This worked for me without a reboot! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. when I restarted the machine it was working fine.it was due to windows updates in pending.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open the registry. For open registry, press window key + R and type

Step 2: Type regedit and press enter button

Step 3: Now selectHKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager

Step 4: Double click "PendingFileRenameOperations"

Step 5: Delete all data from Value data textbox.

Step 6: Press OK and close the registry.

Now try to run SQL Server 2008 setup again. I hope Restart computer failed error not come again.

Comment: welcome to superuser, your answer is close to other answers, it may help you could point out differences as the OP only could get a re-install to make it work. This will help future readers. again welcome to superuser